# How can I move a PictureBox from one panel to another?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, panel, move

I have a Picture Box in a panel and I need to see it move from this panel to another one upon user click. To give you a better picture, I have a connect four game where I have a chip or whatever you call it moving with the mouse on top of the connect four grid and I need it to go in the grid and obviously stay in its place. This is the code I have right now. The chip seems to go down but never stay there

```
Graphics g = grid.CreateGraphics();  

grid.Controls.Add(picBox);

for (int i = 0; i < newYloc; i++)
{
     picBox.Location = new Point(newXloc, picBox.Top + 1);
     // moves the chip by 1 down each iteration
     picBox.Show();
}

if (playerNo == 1) g.DrawImage(red, newXloc, newYloc, 65, 65);
else g.DrawImage(gold, newXloc, newYloc, 65, 65);
```

where grid is the panel where I have the connect four grid, picBox is the Picture Box which before this piece of code resides in another panel.

Comment: Which programming language do you use in your question ?

Comment: this was C# winforms..